# why the program is crushing

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
  #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Shallow {
    private:
        int *data;
    public:
        void set_data_value(int d) { *data = d; }
        int get_data_value() { return *data; }
        // Constructor
        Shallow(int d);
        // Copy Constructor
        Shallow(const Shallow &source);
        // Destructor
        ~Shallow();
    };

    Shallow::Shallow(int d) {
        data = new int;
        *data = d;
    }

    Shallow::Shallow(const Shallow &source) 
        : data(source.data) {
            cout << "Copy constructor  - shallow copy" << endl;
    }

    Shallow::~Shallow() {
        delete data;
        cout << "Destructor freeing data" << endl;
    }

    void display_shallow(Shallow s) {
        cout << s.get_data_value() << endl;
    }

    int main() {

        Shallow obj1 {100};
        display_shallow(obj1);
```

doing alright until here
            Shallow obj2 {obj1};
here where my program stop doing ok
            obj2.set_data_value(1000); `enter code here`
can anyone explain this to me in this point
            return 0;
        }
in the end of my program something going wrong

Comment: `int *data;`? Why a pointer?

Comment: If you use a naked owning pointer as a member variable, you are responsible for handling it properly.  A debugger will be very useful.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: In modern C++, if you use `new` or `delete` you are (almost always) doing something wrong.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the Rule of Three.  I wish people would actually read before closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every call to `Shallow::~Shallow` deletes the `data` pointer's memory, but not every new `Shallow` allocates a new block of memory. Every `delete` needs to correspond to exactly one `new`. But

```
display_shallow(obj1);
```

1) creates a new temporary `Shallow` object (you pass to `display_shallow` by value) which uses the  `data` pointer of `obj1`

2) destroys the temporary, which deletes the block of memory used by both the temporary and `obj1`

`obj2` also shares `obj1`'s pointer, which doesn't point anywhere anymore. When you try to call `obj2.set_data_value(1000)`, you're dereferencing an invalid pointer, which is undefined behavior. You should consider yourself lucky that the program merely crashed, rather than launch a nuclear missile.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: @AntutuCat If you think this answers your question, you can click on the checkmark to accept it.